# Spring-data/Hibernate does not work with null-values properly

Tags: hibernate, spring-data

Passed into spring-data method null-value param is converted to bytea.

Simple test case:

My DAO method to retrive users by telephone number:

```
@Query(value = "select * from user_account  \n"
            + "where case when :telNumber is null then telephone is null\n"
            + "           when :telNumber is not null then telephone = :telNumber end", nativeQuery = true)
    List<ProdUser> findUserByTelephoneNumber(@Param("telNumber") String telNumber);
```

Then unit test:

```
    @Test
    public void testUser(){
    ProdUser user = prodUserEntityDataRepository.findUserByTelephoneNumber("345324333").get(0);
    Assert.assertNotNull(user);
    Assert.assertTrue(user.getTelephone().equals("345324333"));

    List<ProdUser> users = prodUserEntityDataRepository.findUserByTelephoneNumber(null); //Exception here
    Assert.assertNotNull(users);
    Assert.assertTrue(users.size() > 0);
    }
```

On row prodUserEntityDataRepository.findUserByTelephoneNumber(null) I get exception:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bytea
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

SQL parameters log shows that any null value has type bytea, that is not comparable to varchar, nummber, smallint, etc.

Does any one know how to workaround this problem in good way? Does this issue is related to Hibernate bug described in https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9165 ?

For DAO we use Spring-Data over Hibernate. As RDBMS we use PostgreSQL.

PS: for workaround I could use type casting: CAST( :telNumber as varchar), but I do not like this solution. I'd like to disable converting null-params into **bytea**.

UPDATE:

I have even simpler example:

DAO method:

```
@Query(value = "select coalesce(:var1, :var2)", nativeQuery = true)
Long coalesce(@Param("var1") Long var1, @Param("var2") Long var2);
```

Unit Test

```
@Test
    public void coalesce(){
    Assert.assertEquals(prodUserEntityDataRepository.coalesce(1l,2l), Long.valueOf(1l));

    //Here is exeption - org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: COALESCE types bytea and bigint cannot be matched
    Assert.assertEquals(prodUserEntityDataRepository.coalesce(null,2l), Long.valueOf(2l));

    Assert.assertNull(prodUserEntityDataRepository.coalesce(null,null));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT *
FROM user_account
WHERE telephone IS NOT DISTINCT FROM CAST(CAST(:telNumber AS TEXT) AS BIGINT)
```

It works because `IS DISTINCT FROM` accepts `NULL`s and the `CAST`s circumvent a bug in Hibernate/PostgreSQL where `null` parameters are passed as `BYTEA` instead of a regular `NULL` type.